# How to recover lost scene in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just started using Unity, made some progress and built a scene with some prefabs and logic.

While importing some package I downloaded via the package manager, I was asked if I want to open a new scene. Sadly I pressed yes, not knowing that it would erase my previous scene.

I was constantly pressing `CTRL+S` to save while working on my original scene, however I couldn't find any option to go back to my scene from this new scene.

Needless to say that countless `CTRL-Z` hits did not help.
It seems like the new scene replaced the `SampleScene.unity` file my original scene was saved in.

Is there anything I can do to recover the scene ?

Comment: Seems like no hope. For future consider using `git` or other version-control system

Comment: Maybe there is actually some `.unity` file with the scene, somewhere along your files in the project

Comment: This is very disappointing, losing hours of work because of one miss-click. The warning wasn't even that clear about me being able to lose my work.

Comment: if this is a Mac it should be in timemachine.  sorry to hear!

Comment: maybe next time rename your sample scene to something different or create a new scene so that the plugin doesn't overwrite the default scene. I understand the frustration :(

Comment: If you delete items from a project, they end up in the trash. If you replace them, however, I do not know, but check maybe you are lucky.

Comment: More than likely it just created **another** scene leaving your original untouched.  Use Unity's **All Scenes** filter in the Project window to find your scene or failing that, use _Windows File Explorer_ to look for any **.scene** files in your **Assets** folder.  Use the search box

Comment: Search for `DefaultScene` in the assets .. that's the default first scene Unity loads/saves to usually .. if you say you saved all the time then there will be the according Scene asset under `Assets/DefaultScene.unity` except you renamed it.

Comment: However if a package asks to reload the scene then .. well it was overwritten into the exact same file .. and besides proper version control there is no way to undo this

Comment: Thank you all for trying to help.
After trying pretty much everything I decided to start all over. I guess its a good thing i'm just a beginner and didn't put hundreds of hours into this scene.